# Suppose that $A\cap A^g= 1$ for all $g\in G\setminus A$. Then $|\cup A^g| \ge |G|/2 + 1$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $1\neq A\le G$. Suppose that $A\cap A^g=1$ for all $g\in G\setminus A$. Then $|\cup A^g| \ge |G|/2 + 1$.

This is the statement. Suppose $|A|=2$ and $|G|=4$. There are two elements not belonging to $A$, let them be $x$and $y$. Then we have $|A\cup A^x \cup A^y|=3|A|-3+1=4\ge 4/2+1$. How do I generalize?

Comment: If $|G|=4$, then $G$ is abelian, and the condition cannot hold for $|A|=2$ (since $A^g=A$ for all $g\in G$). Your assumption for your example is in fact a contradiction, from which you can prove anything, so I would not put too much stock on your ability to “generalize” anything you do with such assumptions.

Comment: As written, this is false. If $A=\{e\}$, then it certainly satisfies the condition given, but the union of conjugates of $A$ is just $\{e\}$, no matter what the size of $G$ is. You need additional assumptions. You should also specify whether you are assuming that $A$ is a subgroup or not.

Comment: (In addition to the impossible premise, your calculation assumes that $A\cap A^x=A\cap A^y=A^x\cap A^y=\{1\}$. The first two are given; the latter must be proven.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true if $A$ is a non-trivial (proper) *subgroup* of a finite group $G$. In that case $A$ is a so-called [Frobenius complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_group). It requires character theory to show that the *set*
$$N=(G-\underset{g \in G}\bigcup A^g) \cup \{1\} \tag{1}$$
is actually a proper normal subgroup of $G$. Hence $|G:N| \geq 2$ and from $(1)$ it follows that $$|\underset{g \in G}\bigcup A^g)|=|G|-|N|+1 \geq \frac{1}{2}|G|+1.$$

**Note** (after edit and comments of @stf91).
Here is a simple proof.

Since $A$ is a subgroup, we have $A \subseteq N_G(A)=\{g \in G: A^g=A\}$, the normalizer of $A$ in $G$. Now, since $A \cap A^g=1$ for all $g \notin A$, and $A$ is non-trivial, it follows that $A=N_G(A)$. But
$$|\underset{g \in G}\bigcup A^g)|=|G:N_G(A)|(|A|-1)+1=|G:A|(|A|-1)+1.$$

And $|G:A|(|A|-1)+1 \geq \frac{1}{2}|G|+1 \iff \frac{|A|-1}{|A|} \geq \frac{1}{2} \iff |A| \geq 2.$

Comment: I edited the question to add the missing facts. The problem is from Kurzweil and Stellmacher, TheTheory of Finite Groups, An Introduction. It is from the very first section of the first chapter (page 10). So the reader is assumed to only use very elementary facts from group theory. And so the problem can be solved without using character theory. I mean, the proof should be elementary.

Comment: OK, makes sense, and $A$ is just a set, right?

Comment: I can prove that $A^g\cap A^h=1$ for all $g,h$ not belonging to $A$ with $g\neq h$. $|(A^g\cap A^h)^{h^{-1}}|=|A^g\cap A^h|$. But $(A^g\cap A^h)^{h^{-1}}=A^{gh^{-1}}\cap A=1$. So $|A^g\cap A^h|=1$, that is $A^g\cap A^h=1$.

Comment: No, A is a subgroup of the finite group G.

Comment: @stf91 Your argument that $A^g\cap A^h=1$ is incorrect. Note that $g,h\notin A$, $g\neq h$, does **not** imply $gh^{-1}\notin A$, as you are assuming. $gh^{-1}\in A\iff Ag=Ah$, so any two distinct elements of the same right coset of $A$ will yield $gh^{-1}\in A$.

Comment: I give up. Can you give me an elementary proof?

Comment: See my proof edited in the Note.

Comment: @Nicky: Ah... I see. Thanks. However, the reader doesn't yet know the number of conjugates of A is the index of the normalizer of A. He doesn't even know what a normal subgroup is.

Comment: Ok. Of course you do not need to mention/define the normalizer, but construct a well-defined bijective map  between the right cosets of $A$ to the conjugates of $A$, by $Ag \mapsto A^g$. Thereafter the reasoning is the same as I indicated.

Comment: If $Ax=Ay$ then $xy^{-1}\in A$, $A=A^{xy^{-1}}$, $A^y=A^x$. But I find it impossible to go back. To show that $A=A^{xy^{-1}}$ implies $xy^{-1}\in A$.

Comment: If $A^x=A^y$, then $A^{xy^{-1}}=A$. If $xy^{-1} \notin A$, then $A  \cap A^{xy^{-1}}=A \cap A=A=1$, a contradiction. Can you finish?

Comment: Ah..., I thought $Ag \to A^g$ was ALWAYS a bijection! I was wrong, it seems.